# How to select text from other applications using android service?

Tags: android, select, text, service, copy

I want the user to be able to select all text in say, Gmail, at a single double tap, and put the text into my app.

Now, I realize this isn't possible without a rooted device. So I've changed my plans a little.  I want to have a user start a drag on a service that's running through a window manager on the left side of the screen. They will end their drag on a specific word in their Gmail.  The word and all words below this certain y-point be sent to my app.

How can I do this?

Edit: To maybe help focus your thinking, right now, I can 'select all text' using Android's select tool (the copy and paste selection tool). I can then choose my app from the 'Share' dropdown menu and import text that way. How can I do these steps programmatically?

Comment: "How can I do these steps programmatically?" - You can't.